# Produce all the digits in an integer for python except the last

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this function which is to give me the last digit of the number passed. Is there a way to get all the digits except the last one?

```
def lastdigit(num):
    out = num%10
    return out
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644638/how-to-take-the-nth-digit-of-a-number-in-python check here.

Comment: `int(str(121)[:-1])` will give `12`

Comment: `x = 123` then use `int(str(x)[:-1] if len(str(x))>1 else x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def all_digits_except_last(num):
    if abs(num) < 10:
        return None # view comment

    out = num // 10
    return out
```

This snippet of code **integer** divides the number by 10 to get all the digits of the number except the last one - then returns it. It also checks if the integer is only one digit - if that is the case it returns `None`.

However, you could argue that there is no need to check for a single digit as said below.

Comment: Could I recommend changing `len(str(num)) == 1` to `num < 10` or `abs(num) < 10` if there needs to be a special case for single digit numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea to avoid the finicky conversion of integers to strings.

Comment: I think there's no need to check for single digit number. If you want all digits except the last of `7` (which is equivalent to `00007`), shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: Finicky indeed: `len('-1') > 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try multiply:

```
def lastdigit(num):
    return int(num*0.1)
print(lastdigit(12355))
```

Output:

```
1235
```

Comment: Still way more complicated than just using integer division, but better than your other two :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, other answers should be accepted, i am unhappy, that this easy question i can't answer, :), still thank you, but why i say that you could answer,but you don't

Comment: I'm not answering because // was presented already. Everyone has those days. Nothing coffee or sleep can't fix.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hahahahahaha, Yeah correct, that's why i am upset (just joking :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks very very much, Now i am happy :) (hahaha)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
def not_last(x):
    return x // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
>>> def digits(n):
        if n==0: yield 0
        while n>0:
            yield n%10
            n = n/10


>>> n = 123456
>>> all_digits_except_last = [d for d in digits(n)][1:]
>>> all_digits_except_last
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use slicing for this.
like:-

```
    def except_last_digit(num):
        convert_to_str = str(num)
        length_of_str = len(convert_to_str)
        except_last_digit = 
        convert_to_str[0:length_of_str-1]
        convert_to_int = int(except_last_digit)
        return convert_to_int
```

Answer (score 0):

Handling digits is better done by casting your integer to a string.

```
def firstdigits(num):
    return str(num)[:-1]

firstdigits(121) # '12'
```