# How to detect if the middle digit of an integer is "0" without converting it into a string?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Trying to make a function which detects the the middle digit of an odd number is 0 and returns True if it is, otherwise False. I really want to get this function to work without converting the integer to a string first.

This is what I have so far:

```
def test(n): 
  n = str(n)
  if len(n) % 2 == 0:
      return False
  else:
      left_side = n[:len(n)//2]
      right_side = n[(len(n)//2):]

      if right_side[:1] == "0" and ((not "0" in left_side)and (not "0" in right_side[2:])):
          return True
      else:
          return False


print (test(0)) # True
print (test(101)) # True
print (test(123)) # False
print (test(21031)) # True
```

Comment: Honestly, doing the manual math here probably isn't worth it from a performance or readability standpoint. I've timed cases like this in Python and Clojure, and string manipulation is usually almost as fast, and is much simpler.

Comment: @Carcigenicate is that so? Also is my method the most "Pythonic" way to make this function? I was given a tester for this function and it doesn't seem to be able to pass it for some reason and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Use the modulus operator `% 10` repeatedly to create a sequence of remainders.

Comment: @PeterWood Fairly new to python, do you mind elaborating on what you mean by "Use the modulus operator % 10 "?

Comment: You'd have to time this exact case to know for sure, but I wouldn't worry about it unless you were finding that `test` was becoming a bottleneck. And a review of how Pythonic is is would be beyond here. Once you can get the code to work though in your own testing, it can be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) as a review request.

Comment: Those are your search terms.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 12345
digits = []
while n:
    digit = n % 10
    digits.append(digit)
    n //= 10

digit_count = len(digits)

if digit_count % 2:
    middle = digit_count // 2
    print(digits[middle])
```

Output:

```
3
```

Alternatively, using [**`math.log10`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log10):

```
from math import log10

n = 12345

digit_count = int(log10(n)) + 1
middle = digit_count // 2

print(n // 10 ** middle % 10)
```

See these two answers:

[Length of an integer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2189827/1084416)

[How to take the nth digit of a number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39644726/1084416)

Comment: I think that my phrasing of the question confused you a bit. I don't want the middle element of any given odd number, I want the function to detect if the middle digit of an odd number is "0" if it is, I'd like it to return True

Comment: @snk Peter's not confused, you just need to fill in the last step yourself. If you know how to get the middle digit, you can check whether it's zero.

Comment: You could use divmod to save a line: `n, digit = divmod(n, 10)`

Comment: @wjandrea if we can use `divmod` I'd use `log10` instead to find how many digits there were and `n // 10**middle % 10` to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it will make much difference in terms of performance, but you can use the `log` function to compute the number of zeros in a number and remove the rightmost half by dividing to the correct power of 10. For example:

```
import math

def test(n):
  if n == 0:
    return True
  digits = math.ceil(math.log(n + 1, 10)) - 1
  return digits % 2 == 0 and not (n // 10**(digits / 2) % 10)
```

Comment: This usually works but in a misleading way.  To correctly calculate digits you would need `digits = ceil(log(n+1, 10))`.  Then your logic should be `digits % 2 == 1 ...`.  As written this succeeds in several cases thanks to rounding.  e.g. failure: `test(1000000) == False` but it should be `True`

Comment: @Cireo Right, my bad. The original method you suggested should work fine. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it. it does convert it to a string, but honestly it's faster, easier, and just more efficient.

```
num = int(input("number too test: "))


def test(number):
    num_len = len(str(number))
    print(num_len)
    if num_len % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        number = str(number)
        half = int((num_len-1)/2)
        print(number[half])
        if int(number[half]) is 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


test(num)
```