# Remove first 5 from numbers in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list with numbers like this :-

```
s = [5542, 5654, 7545]
```

The goal is to remove the first 5 from the number such that the resultant list is like this

```
s = [542, 654, 745]
```

What's the best way to achieve the following without using any external libraries?

Comment: Convert each number to a string, check if the digit `'5'` is in the string, if so, remove it from the string, and convert the string back to an integer.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon Well, Thinking of the best approach. :)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822), and try to break problems down into logical steps before asking. For example, if you can solve the problem for a single input integer, do you see how to repeat that logic for the entire list? If not, then that is a separate question to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/); if so, then it is a separate question to **omit** from the [mre]. Aside from that, what do you think it actually **means** to "remove a digit" from the integer?

Comment: If, for example, you have understood that integers **do not have** digits (nor bits, nor nybbles), and that only a **textual representation of** an integer has those things, then you might think in terms of converting to and from a string. Each conversion is a separate question (and common duplicates at that); the string processing is arguably two questions (how to figure out where the `5` is, and how to remove a text character at that position).

Comment: On the other hand, if you are thinking in terms of place-value arithmetic, then figuring out each numeric digit **value** is an **arithmetic** question. That, too, is a common duplicate. In fact, both digit extraction methods are addressed in [How to take the nth digit of a number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644638).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with `str.replace(old, new, count)` -

```
[int(str(i).replace('5','',1)) for i in s]
```

```
[542, 654, 745]
```

The `str.replace(old, new, count)` in this case has 3 parameters, where the `count` set to 1 will only replace the first instance of 5 it finds in the string.

Then you can convert it back to an integer.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [answer], and do not allow others to treat the site as a code-writing service. It would be better to go somewhere that you would at least get paid for it. If a problem obviously and directly breaks down into separate logical steps, then it inherently "Needs More Focus" and should be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
s = [int(str(x)[:str(x).index("5")] + str(x)[str(x).index("5") + 1:]) for x in s]
```